# Depth of polynomial ring $S=\Bbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n,...]$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider the polynomial ring of countable variables with coefficients in the real numbers, i.e, $S=\Bbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n,...]$. My Question is about the **depth** of this ring.

**Question**: *Could we find any maximal ideal in $S$ such that it contains an  **anti-chain** with uncountable number of prime ideals*?

**PS**: We recall that a set $\{P_{\alpha}\} _{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ is an anti-chain of prime ideals if for each $u ,v \in T$, neither $P_{u} \subseteq P_{v}$ nor $P_{v} \subseteq P_{u}$.

**PPS**: By this notation, I am seeking an anti-chain $\{P_{\alpha}\} _{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ of prime ideals in $S$ for which $T$ is uncountable.

Comment: Can't we take $P_u = (x - uy)$ for any real number $u$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same spirit as the answer to your [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146157/chain-of-prime-ideals-in-polynomial-ring-s-bbbrx-1-x-2-x-n), pick a bijection $\phi$ from the natural numbers to the rationals.  For each real number $\alpha$, let $I_\alpha$ be the ideal generated by all $x_n$ such that $\phi(n)<\alpha$ and let $J_\alpha$ be the ideal generated by all $x_n$ such that $\phi(n)>\alpha+1$.  Let $P_\alpha=I_\alpha+J_\alpha$.  The $P_\alpha$ form an uncountable anti-chain contained in the maximal ideal of $S$ generated by all the $x_n$.

Comment: WoooW!!! what a versatile and basic notion. Thank you very much dear Professor Landsburg. I like the unique and special trick you have used in both of my questions.